# "One or more parameter values were invalid" error in aws

Tags: reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I mistakenly updated my shema through my react app today and since I had made changes on appsync this changes were lost. Now I have taken my time and reacreated the lost tables and made resolvers n so on but now all my queries which filter based on the table index have stopped working. I constantly get the following error:

```
 One or more parameter values were invalid: Condition parameter type
 does not match schema type (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400;
     Error Code: ValidationException; 
Request ID: PP50VGJ3P7GIE46BL619R6IB0VVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
```

here is a look at my resolver:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "index": "userId-index",
    "query" : {
        "expression": "userId = :userId",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":userId" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.identity.sub)
        }
    },
    "nextToken":   #if( $context.args.nextToken )
      "$context.args.nextToken"
     #else
       null
    #end
}
```

I don't understand what the problem is but hope some one can help me. 
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved mistakenly changed my api from cognito pools to api key thus the error.